# Как добавить значение переменной внутри python кода?

Tags: python, airflow

Как можно добавить в название создаваемой таблицы дату и время запуска таска?

```
with DAG("inform",
         schedule_interval="55 17 * * 1-5",
         start_date=days_ago(1),
         catchup=False,
         tags=["Adb"]) as dag:

create_report_2 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='create_report_2',
    postgres_conn_id='adb',
    sql="""
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {Timestamp}_r_segment_status;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {Timestamp}_r_segment_status AS
        SELECT dbid, "content", "role", preferred_role, "mode", status, hostname
        FROM pg_catalog.gp_segment_configuration;
    """
)
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что это хорошее решение? Обычно таблицу используют одну и ту же, а дату и время пишут в какое-то поле таблицы. Нет смысла плодить таблицы, да и мониторить их замучаетесь.

Comment: Тоже так думаю. И скорее всего так и сделаю.
Но все равно нужно  записать дату и время в переменную, так как её я буду использовать в нотификациях других тасков.

Как я понял, для этого надо написать нечто подобное?
**def current_time():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
cur_date = current_time()**

Comment: Да, что-то такое. А для подстановки переменной в запрос можете использовать f-строки, если там нет готового механизма какого-то для подстановки параметров.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
start_task_time = datetime.now()
sql_query = f"same code for sql {start_task_time}"
```

Так же в схожей задаче, я добавлял отдельную колонку по событиям. Выглядело это примерно так. Колонка тип datetime

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без f перед строкой у вас подстановка работает? Впрочем, я DAG слабо знаю, может там и так подставляет.

Comment: Не опечатался. спасибо